# How to properly declare a dynamic set of generic T value contained within a Map/Record

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, generics

I've been struggling to figure out how to properly map a dynamic generic value mapped from a explicitly typed set of string keys.

Essentially I want to have a set of templated functions that follow a distinct pattern where two different values of the function can be generic, The "value" parameter and the "additionalProps". Here is a brief code snippet showcasing how they are declared.

```js
// :: Base types ::
export type CellTemplate = "checkbox" | "badge" | "label" | "link";
export interface CustomCellRenderer<
  TValue = unknown,
  TRendererProps = unknown
> {
  (
    value: TValue,
    key: string,
    label: string,
    row: unknown,
    additionalProps?: TRendererProps
  ): JSX.Element;
}
// :: Base types ::

// :: Implementations ::

type LinkCellRendererProps = {
  linkTo?: string;
};
export type LinkCustomCellRendererType = CustomCellRenderer<
  string,
  LinkCellRendererProps
>;
export type LabelCustomCellRendererType = CustomCellRenderer<string>;
export type CheckboxCustomCellRendererType = CustomCellRenderer<boolean>;
export type BadgeCustomCellRendererType = CustomCellRenderer<string | string[]>;


// Each cell renderer follows a similar pattern, example:
export const BadgeCellRenderer: BadgeCustomCellRendererType = function (
  value: string | string[],
  key: string,
  label: string,
  row: unknown
): JSX.Element {
...etc
// So for each renderer they specify their type as XXXRendererType
// :: Implementations ::
```

I've been trying to Map CellTemplate to CustomCellRenderer so that when the developer specifies a string of type CellTemplate, it should bring the appropriate CustomCellRenderer.

So far I've tried creating explicit const maps like this:

```js
function makeMap<K>(map: Record<CellTemplate, K>): Record<CellTemplate, K> {
  return map;
}
//Hack: Figure out how to support a map of dynamic T value types.
const CustomComponentRenderer = makeMap({
  checkbox: CheckBoxCellRenderer,
  badge: BadgeCellRenderer,
  label: LabelCellRenderer,
  link: LinkCellRenderer,
});
```

But obviously K gets confused between values as LabelCellRenderer might declare its generic type as string and CheckBoxCellRenderer might declare it as boolean

**making `makeMap<any>` works** but I lose all the typing I need later on for when I want to expose it to the developer using this interface:

```js
SampleProps<TCellTemplate extends CellTemplate = CellTemplate> {
  template?: TCellTemplate;
  templateAdditionalProps?: (row: TRow) => typeof CustomComponentRenderer[TCellTemplate];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `XXXRenderer` components?

Comment: I've added it for one so you can know how the rest of the components behave

Comment: I'm confused: why don't you just make the const map without passing it through `makeMap()`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMOykw)?  Surely there's something you're trying to do that doesn't work if you do that, but I don't see it in the code.  Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates an unmet use case?